# Chrome webNavigation with overlapping urlFilters fires multiple times

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have two different handlers listening on the `onCompleted` event. If they coincidentally match/overlap the same url and are both executed, it calls both handlers multiple times.

Example:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(
    () => {
        console.log('aaa')
        // would run some custom logic here
    },
    { url: [{ urlContains: 'git' }] },
)
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(
    () => {
        console.log('bbb')
        // other custom logic
    },
    { url: [{ urlContains: 'hub' }] },
)
```

The above logs on navigating to `github.com`:

```
aaa
bbb
aaa
bbb
```

I would it expect it to log each statement once. If navigating to a URL that just matches the first listener filter (eg `git-tower.com`), it logs it only once - so this only seems to happen if both are triggered.

Why is this having an exponential (n^n) effect?

Comment: https://crbug.com/1005009. The "solution" is to not use multiple listeners I guess.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate =/

Answer (score 0):

Make one listener for both filters

```
const urlFilters = [{urlContains: 'git'}, {urlContains: 'hub'}];
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function(details) {
    if (details.frameId === 0) {
        console.log('aaa')
        // would run some custom logic here
    }else {
        //subframe navigation
    }
},{url: urlFilters})
```